# Atualizar table html após cadastrar usuário usando ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, tabela-html

Olá, tenho um seguinte código js para cadastrar um usuário.

```
$(function() {

    $('#cadastrar_usuario').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formDados = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'func_cadastrar_usuario.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formDados,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#resultado').html(data);

            },

            complete: function(data) {
                $('#cadastrar_usuario').each(function() {
                    this.reset();
                });

            },

            dataType: 'html'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

e tenho uma tabela html onde eu listo os usuários cadastrados no banco com PHP.

gostaria de saber como fazer com que após o cadastro do usuário, essa tabela de usuários seja atualizada sem refresh ou reload, como eu faço na hora de cadastrar. Tipo, no complete da função de cadastrar, eu atualizar a tabela.

OBS: no arquivo func_cadastrar_usuario.php, eu apenas recebo os dados do formulário de cadastro, ai faço o insert e cadastro no banco. Se der para fazer por lá também serve.

Agradeço de coração por qualquer ajuda.

**Estarei deixando aqui o meu arquivos usuarios.php, onde tem um div com a tabelas de listagem de usuários do banco, e uma div com um formulário para cadastro de usuários.**

```
<div id="listar">
    <table id="exibir_dados" width="660" height="115">
        <tr id="titulos">
        <td width="30" height="32">ID</td>
        <td width="330">NOME</td>
        <td width="166">E-MAIL</td>
        <td width="70">SEXO</td>
        <td width="5">LOGIN</td>
        <td width="86">AÇÔES</td>
        </tr>

        <?php
            include("conexao.php");
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id ASC");

            $c = 2;
            $cores = array("#FFFFFF","#EAF4FF");


            while($coluna = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $id    = $coluna["id"];
                $nome  = $coluna["nome"];
                $email = $coluna["email"];
                $sexo  = $coluna["sexo"]; 
                $login = $coluna["login"];

                $index = $c % 2;
                $c++;
                $cor = $cores[$index];

         ?>
              <tr id="lista" bgcolor="<?=$cor?>">
                <td width="30" height="32"><?php echo $id;?></td>
                <td width="165"><?php echo $nome;?></td>
                <td width="166"><?php echo $email;?></td>
                <td width="87"><?php echo $sexo;?></td>
                <td width="134"><?php echo $login;?></td>
                <td width="86"><a id="alterar" href="">Alterar</a><a href="" id="<?php echo $id;?>" class="excluir">Excluir</a></td>
              </tr>
          <?php
          }
          ?>
    </table>      
    </div>


    <div id="usuario">
        <h1>CADASTRO DE USUÁRIOS</h1>
        <form id="cadastrar_usuario" action="" method="post" class="form_group">
            <table id="cadastrar">
                    <p id="resultado" hidden=""></p>
                  <tr> 
                    <td id="titulo">Nome:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="txt" name="nome" id="nome" maxlength="30" placeholder="Insira um Nome" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td id="titulo">E-mail:</td>
                    <td><input type="email" class="txt" name="email" id="email" maxlength="30" placeholder="Insira um E-mail"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td id="titulo">Sexo:</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="sexo" id="masc" value="masculino" checked/> <label for="masc">Masculino</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="fem" value="feminino"/> <label for="fem">Feminino</label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td id="titulo">Login:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="txt" name="login" id="login" maxlength="15" placeholder="Insira um login" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td id="titulo">Senha:</td> 
                    <td><input type="password" class="txt" name="senha" id="senha" maxlength="8" placeholder="8 dígitos" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><button type="submit">Cadastrar</button></td>
                  </tr>
             </table>
         </form>
    </div>
```

**Arquivo func_cadastrar_usuario.php, onde eu cadastro o usuários**

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");


@$nome  = $_POST["nome"]; 
@$email = $_POST["email"];
@$sexo  = $_POST["sexo"];
@$login = $_POST["login"];
@$senha = md5($_POST["senha"]);

if(empty($nome)){

    echo"<script>alert('Campo Nome está vazio!!!');</script>";

}elseif(empty($email)){

    echo"<script>alert('Campo E-mail está vazio!!!');</script>";

}elseif(empty($login)){

    echo"<script>alert('Insira um Login!!!');</script>";

}elseif($senha == 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'){

    echo"<script>alert('Insira uma Senha!!!');</script>";

}else{

    $consuta = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login'"));

    if($consuta == 1){

        echo"<script>alert('Login já cadastrado!!!'); </script>";

    }else{

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, sexo, login, senha) VALUES ('". $nome ."','". $email ."', '". $sexo ."', '". $login ."', '". $senha ."')");
        echo"<script>alert('Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!!!');</script>";
    }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Não percebi se queres atualizar no HTML ou na base de dados? Se fôr no HTML podes colocar um exemplo de tabela?

Comment: eu tenho uma página com 1 tabela html que lista os dados do banco, e um formulário que cadastrar um usuário. Na parte de cadastrar eu uso a função com ajax que eu postei  onde eu cadastro o usuário sem fazer reload. O que eu quero é que quando eu cadastre um usuário, a tabela html que lista os usuários já cadastrados, seja atualizada com o novo usuário cadastrado.

Comment: e eu gostaria de atualizar a tabela na mesma função que eu cadastro o usuário, tipo na parte de success ou complete da função.

Comment: Que informação estás a passar em `data` aqui `$('#resultado').html(data);`?

Comment: é apenas um campo hidden que eu utilizo para fazer um verificação,ela não tem muita importância, não se preocupe.

Comment: A minha ideia é passares nesse data a informação se o insert foi bem sucedido. E caso sim, podes fazer `append` na table com os dados da form antes de fazeres `.reset`

Comment: perfeito, poderia fazer um exemplo? se precisar de alguma parte de código de algum arquivo...

Comment: Preciso de uma parte do teu código que [já referi em cima...](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140955/atualizar-table-html-ap%c3%b3s-cadastrar-usu%c3%a1rio-usando-ajax?noredirect=1#comment291893_140955), um exemplo de como é essa tabela e os campos do formulário.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que cries um template no lado do servidor. No fundo é um pedaço que podes copiar, inserir os novos dados e colocar na tabela.

Assim no servidor gera isto quando a página gerada:

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td data-name="id"></td>
        <td data-name="nome"></td>
        <td data-name="email"></td>
        <td data-name="sexo"></td>
        <td data-name="login"></td>
        <td width="86"><a id="alterar" href="">Alterar</a><a href="" id="" class="excluir">Excluir</a></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Depois no JavaScript vais buscar essa `tr` cloná-la e inserir os dados novos:

```
$('#cadastrar_usuario').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    var formDados = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'func_cadastrar_usuario.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formDados,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#resultado').html(data);
            var tr = document.querySelector('template').content.querySelector("tr");
            var clone = document.importNode(tr, true);
            $(clone).find('td').each(function() {
                var type = this.dataset.type;
                if (type) {
                    this.innerTHML = form.querySelector('[name="' + type + '"]').value;
                } else {
                    // caso da ultima td
                    $(this).find('a').last().attr('id', form.querySelector('[name="id"]').value);
                }
            });
            $('#exibir_dados').append(clone);
        },
```

### Nota:

- no teu código há vários erros, é possivel que a minha solução não funcione à primeira, mas mostra-te o caminho a seguir.
- desaconselho usar CSS em atributos, inline, como `<td width="30"`. Isso dificulta muito a manutenção do código.
- os IDs têm de ser únicos. Nenhum elemento da página pode ter o mesmo ID que um outro. Essa é a diferença fundamental entre `class` e `id`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos conselhos e pela atenção que tem me dado. Realmente não funcionou de primeira mais irei "fuçar" um pouco aqui.

Comment: @JoelsonSantos tinha-me esquecido de `$('#exibir_dados').append(clone);`, juntei agora. Sim, faz isso. Se quiseres podes colocar aqui o erro que te dá na consola.

Comment: @JoelsonSantos após testar seu código, seguindo as orientações da resposta, é aconselhável substituir as funções `mysql_`, por `mysqli_`.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php